# Makerbot Won t Install

Tags: apt

When I try to install Makerbot I get this:

W: Failed to fetch http://﻿﻿downloads.makerbot.com/makerware/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://﻿﻿downloads.makerbot.com/makerware/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Could not resolve '﻿﻿downloads.makerbot.com'

Please help

Comment: Seems like a temporary unaccessible website. I can reach  http://downloads.makerbot.com/makerware/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg

Comment: It should be on y our end. The link works fine.

Comment: You will need to contact MakerBot support for issues with anything hosted on their servers.

Comment: the website seems fine, but that doesn't change the fact there is a problem.

Comment: as far as it being "on my end", I found another post about it so i don't think it isolated.  moreover i am just following simple instructions i have followed on other machines without problem.  i doubt i introduced an error.  but still, let me ask.  since i posted, have you verified yourself that there is not a problem?  if so, that might be helpful to me.

Comment: Lastly, I am aware that the proper course of action is to talk with Makerbot directly, but they are very bad about getting back to people (I have already tried).  so it seemed at least possible that others had this issue and had solved it, which is why i have asked here.

Comment: The website resolves fine for me. Are you having issues reaching other sites? You (AND the other poster you mentioned) may have a DNS problem.

Comment: I am able to reach the websites.  But after adding the repo and the key, when I update, the repo won't load with the above error noted.  Consequently, I can't "apt-get install makerware".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For OP and for anybody else that finds this-

The problem is that you (and I) copy-pasted the instructions on MakerBot's website. The text on the website includes non-ascii characters that are visually similar to characters you recognize, and end up not showing up. Compare:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep ^deb | grep makerbot | hd
00000000  64 65 62 20 68 74 74 70  3a 2f 2f 64 6f 77 6e 6c  |deb http://downl|
00000010  6f 61 64 73 2e 6d 61 6b  65 72 62 6f 74 2e 63 6f  |oads.makerbot.co|
00000020  6d 2f 6d 61 6b 65 72 77  61 72 65 2f 75 62 75 6e  |m/makerware/ubun|
00000030  74 75 20 74 72 75 73 74  79 20 6d 61 69 6e 0a 64  |tu trusty main.d|
00000040  65 62 20 68 74 74 70 3a  2f 2f ef bb bf ef bb bf  |eb http://......|
00000050  64 6f 77 6e 6c 6f 61 64  73 2e 6d 61 6b 65 72 62  |downloads.makerb|
00000060  6f 74 2e 63 6f 6d 2f 6d  61 6b 65 72 77 61 72 65  |ot.com/makerware|
00000070  2f 75 62 75 6e 74 75 20  74 72 75 73 74 79 20 6d  |/ubuntu trusty m|
00000080  61 69 6e 0a                                       |ain.|
00000084
```

The first 'deb' line was typed in by hand; the second resulted from copy-pasting MakerWare's apt-add-repository command line. Observe the unprintable characters between http:// and downloads (rendered on the right as periods; on the left as ef bb bf ef bb bf)

tl;dr: Don't copy-paste the command. Either type the whole apt-add-repository thing by hand, or add the following one line to /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://downloads.makerbot.com/makerware/ubuntu trusty main
```