# Issues installing makerware on Ubuntu Linux 15.04 vivid

Tags: makerware

I will refer you to this post.

[Makerbot Won t Install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528051/makerbot-won-t-install)

It is similiar to what I am getting I get a failed download.

I am running Ubuntu 15.04 vivid 64 bit.

I am following these steps from the makerware website.  It should work on this linux.

Step 1 is where I have the issue.  When I run that command nothing is returned but I continue on.  I get to step 3 and that is where the major issue seems to be with a clear failure message.

I am getting to step 3 and getting failures.  Below is the code form my terminal window.

Please put things in lamens terms I coming from windows 7 and looking to explore Makerbot on ubuntu as some have said its better.

I would post more details but apparently I need rep to post more than 2 links or 10 rep points just to post a picture.

my error reads W: failed to fetch "url" 404 not found

Answer (score 1):

Yeah just been through this process myself and discovered makerbot software is simply not up to date. For example it has dependences compiled against Mesa 10.5.9 and we are currently at 11.1.

I simply don't want to roll back a HUGE chunk of my Linux 15.04 install to satisfy this software so will give it a pass.

Cura appears to work btw, however I have yet to figure out howto connect up my EcubMaker with it just yet (profiles all set to go, just no communication over USB/COMS, even thought it connects).

Answer (score 0):

try to edit the sources on ubuntu software center and force to install the UTOPIC packages instead the VIVID ones.
I tried and it works but i can't install makerware cause dependencies (conveyor), i think we've too newer packages in our sistem and we have to wait newer version of makerware, finally compatible.